# how to use lambda without jack compiler or retrolambda?

Tags: android, lambda, java-8

The jack compiler is deprecated now, and retrolambda is not an official way to use lambda.

Is there any other way to use lambda in Andorid ?

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html You may want to explain your use case in more detail.

Comment: My recommendation is to use Kotlin and not require a workaround for use of lambdas. As Kotlin is now an officially supported Android development language, you can trust it as an "official way to use lambda". If you need to stick to Java, Morrison Chang's answer provides more guidance. https://kotlinlang.org/

Comment: The reason, Jack is deprecated, is that is has been superseded by builtin support. So what’s your question?